# Adding images with option tag

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down list. I want to add images along with it. I tried adding `img` tag inside tha `option` tag... But still the images are not getting displayed.
How do I do it using `option` tag?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not possible, as [`<option>` only supports text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

You may have to roll your own drop-down control using complex HTML/CSS/JavaScript. How to do it may or may not be within the scope of your question.

Alternatively, you may use a non-repeating `background-image` and apply some padding on the text to achieve a similar effect. But if each `<option>` is to have a unique image, your code is going to be polluted with a `style` attribute for every single `<option>`. If you don't mind that, it's fine. Otherwise, roll your own somehow.

Comment: but `background-image` not work in all browsers..

Comment: deadlink deadlink

Comment: @Ash [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) is a new link.