# Include images in <option> (For a <select>) html form

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding images with option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag)

Is it possible to (instead of text values) store an image inside the  part of the  html form?

Comment: please stop including `[HTML HELP]` in the topic of your questions. Use the tagging system.

Answer (score 3):

If by store you mean display next to items in a drop-down list, yes, it is possible with some fiddling.

What about something like these?

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements#9

You'll probably need jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

No, an html `select` element can take only textual options, using the `option` tag.

If you want to use images then you'd have to use a styled `ul` (or other) element.