# How to put image into the select menu

Tags: html, css, html-select

How can I put image next to the text in the select menu.

For example this is not working:

```
<select style="background-color:black; width:150px;color:white;">
   <option style="background-image:url(images/english.png);">English</option>
</select>
```

This is not working. I want to have a little flag first and then name of the language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag

Comment: If you're jquery proficient then check this [plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select element does not support that type of thing. It's meant to be a native control that's consistent wherever it's used. You can, however, whip up your own custom drop-down style menu.

[Here](http://gigsperusd.com/)'s one I did (under the graph).
Also, [here](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/)'s a jquery plugin that might make it easier for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Neither of your links are valid.

Comment: well, ~16 months ago jamielottering had a public repo for his jquery plugin and I had the domain perusd.com. I'll update the link to mine.