# Possible to insert an icon element inside an <select> or <option>?

Tags: html, dom

Would like to add an icon to a custom-styled select to make it more clear that it's a dropdown menu:

```
// load fontawesome from header with <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<select name="category">
  <option value="0">Category <i class="fa-sort-asc fa"></i></option>
</select>
```

I can get the icon to show up elsewhere in the template but not within the selection/option. I assume this just isn't possible?

Comment: If you're thinking of styling SELECT control I think you're better of with plugins like http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ otherwise there's very little you can do

Comment: option only accepts text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag

Answer (score 0):

Since its a font, not an icon, it actually should work!
I guess not working is how the font-awesome css inserts the character by CSS. so if u insert the UTF character directly into the HTML and specify the font by your own, it should work!

Answer (score -1):

try select2 I used it before few times.
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/