# Angular select with images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

I need to insert flags inside the language select. I have searched in Google and StackOverflow but the solutions founded are not working for me.

**THE CODE:**

In the controller:

```
 $scope.language_list = [{'name': 'english', 'url': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/gb.png'},{'name': 'italian', 'url': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/it.png'}];
```

In the view:

```
<select ng-model="language_selected">
    <option ng-repeat="language in language_list" data-image="{{language.url}}" >{{language.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**EXAMPLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/168/

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i insert images inside the angular select?

**EDIT:**

Here is the Plunker of the solution, cleaned up:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hMlNjkDL3l0QKF37pCa0?p=preview

Comment: use angular ui select https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other answers you can not use `<options>` to add an image, however you can use angular module [`ui-select`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) to achieve what you want to do.

Here is a [**demo with ui-select with your data**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Uks2e7tJ78Ax5bMbup2?p=preview).

Clean up the code and get what you need.

If you're not interested in search box override the CSS as,

```
 .select2-search {
      display: none;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/f80OwHRTKueyrbKRoV7H?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

this is impossible with a native select element,

therfore, you need to design a selectbox using other html elements & css,

try this out:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

//app.directive('appDirective', function() {});
//app.factory('appService', function() {});

function AppCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.obj={language_selected : {'name':'Choose a language'}};
    $scope.language_list = [{'name': 'english', 'url': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/gb.png'},{'name': 'italian', 'url': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/master/png/16/country-4x3/it.png'}];
    
}
```

```css
.select_list{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
}
.select_list:after{
    content:"▼";
    position:absolute;
    right:3px;
    color:#b3b3b3;
}
.select_list > .options{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:-1px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.select_list.active > .options{
    display:block;
}

.select_list > span, .select_list > .options li {
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    list-style:none;
}

.select_list > .options li:hover {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="select_list" ng-class='{active:active}' ng-click="active=!active">
    <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+obj.language_selected.url+')'}">{{obj.language_selected.name}}</span>
    <ul class="options">
        <li class="select_list_option" ng-repeat="language in language_list" ng-click="obj.language_selected=language" ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+language.url+')'}">{{language.name}}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**The Answer:**

Its simply not possible.

The permitted content of a `<option>` tag is Text with eventually escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).
HTML isnt allowed.

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) for more information.

**The solution:**

Make a custom Dropdown with CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, as [`<option>` only supports text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html).

You may have to roll your own drop-down control using complex HTML/CSS/JavaScript. How to do it may or may not be within the scope of your question.

Alternatively, you may use a non-repeating `background-image` and apply some padding on the text to achieve a similar effect. But if each `<option>` is to have a unique image, your code is going to be polluted with a `style` attribute for every single `<option>`. If you don't mind that, it's fine. Otherwise, roll your own somehow.

Referred from : [Adding images with option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting images you could generate css classes (from the language name or adding a new value only for that) and add the images as background images in your css (using sprites).

```
<select ng-model="language_selected">
    <option ng-repeat="language in language_list" ng-class="{{ language.name }}" >{{ language.name }}</option>
</select>
```

For the css sprites I usually use [sass with compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/).