# Setting a default option for a <select> with background images

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<select>` element in which the options are presented as images (specified within the CSS). The `<select>` and `<option>` elements render as expected, but setting the default option seems to have no effect.

The first/default option within the select renders as an empty box:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<select id="select__avatar" value="avatars-03.png" name="select__avatar">
  <option value="avatars-01.png"></option>
  <option value="avatars-02.png"></option>
  <option value="avatars-03.png" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="avatars-04.png"></option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
#select__pick_stock_avatar option {
    width: 30px;
    height: 34px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-01.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-01.png");  
}
#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-02.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-02.png");  
}
#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-03.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-03.png");  
}
#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-04.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-04.png");  
}
```

The default option renders as a blank. I'd like to be able to set the default option server-side, with the value depending on settings specific to the logged-in user. Is there a way to get the default to show the specified default option/image?

Answer (score 1):

The option tag does not accept a background picture, you can style a background gradient color but not an image..it is an html standard

example

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(rgb(55,105,129),rgb(101,201,145));
```

Comment: Thanks, repzero. Well, the background images of the options within the selector are rendering, with the exception of the null/first option, but now that I examine the behavior more closely, it seems that clicking on an element does not change the image of the first element; so it seems the problem is not simply with setting the default element, and I need to re-articulate this question...

Comment: what browser version are you using..I had this same issue and attempted several solutions which proved futile...see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag

Comment: I posted this question after trying it out on Firefox 42. Just checked it out on Opera and IE, and it's failing to render the images, so it seems you're right in being averse to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could set css to "#select__avatar":

```
#select__avatar{
    background-image: url(avatars-03.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-01.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-01.png") !important;  
}
#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-02.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-02.png") !important;  
}
#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-03.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-03.png") !important;  
}
#select__pick_stock_avatar option[value="avatars-04.png"]  {    
     background-image:url("../images/avatars-04.png") !important;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use this approach, because I'd like to be able to specify the default option (depending on settings specific to the logged-in user) in the python code that generates the HTML elements. I'll clarify that in the question.