# Image inside dropdown on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to create a search box with a dropdown inside the search text field and i want add a different image for every option

For now this is my result:

http://www.bootply.com/TqXN4y8Se5

The image are not visible, in dropdown are not possible add image?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag

Answer (score 1):

the html option tag does support text only

see other pst [Adding images with option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562149/adding-images-with-option-tag)

altough you could use bootstraps dropdown component.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

altough it requires custom javascript to listen to changes and react accordingly.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a background image but it's not available cross-browser. Or you can use jquery like http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render